In a straight and level flight if thrust is equal to drag how is aircraft moving forward?
If two forces are equal and acting in opposite direction should not the object remain stationary.
Is there an excess thrust which actually pushes the aircraft forward ?

Per Newton's first law,

A body remains at rest, or in motion at a constant speed in a straight line, except insofar as it is acted upon by a force.

You need excess thrust to get up to speed. But once you are at your target speed, if you make sure there is no net force acting on the airplane by matching thrust to drag, the aircraft will remain in motion.

Similarly an object in space is neither experiencing thrust or drag (if no engines are firing and it's high enough above the atmosphere). So you could say that thrust equals drag (0=0), and yet the object continues in forward motion, affected only by gravity pulling from various directions.

Drag is produced by moving through the air- more speed means more drag. Thrust is the motive force that pushes the plane through the air- more thrust means more push.
At cruise, push equals drag and speed is constant- but not zero. Acceleration is zero in this case, not speed.
